# How to Reduce the Page loading time in angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, loading

I have done one project in angular4 with.Net web API as a backend when I am trying to open my side it is taking 1 to 2 min to load all times, I am aware of lazy loading concept and module division but  we are not able to use it at this stage, plz suggest me if we have any other alternative, it may be a great help for me

Comment: Load time is Depeand open your api data and net speed

Comment: Are you using observable or promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of you need to be know why it's taking your resources this long time to load. Is it due to server or caching or the file itself is too large?

You can test your website on [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/) and get a detailed report.

Additionally, try implementing caching in Angular. There are enough npm packages available.